# How to Add new Currency in Magento2?

Tags: magento2

I want to add  New currency which is displaying in the currency Setup tab in the back-end.

I want to add Points Currency and apply  to the entire store.
Can anyone please help me ??
Thank you!!!

Comment: Do you mean to add new currency which is not available in magento2?

Comment: yes that one only.

Answer (score 1):

To add new currency go to Stores->Configuration->General->Currency Setup and open Currency Options tab.
[image]

If there is no required currency then most likely you will need to update your Magento to the latest version.

If you want to add the “Points Currency” you can choose several currencies. For instance, add unused "Azerbaijani Manat (1993–2006)" as the second currency. Go to Stores->Currency Rates, set the ratio of the base currency to "AZM". Then go to Stores-> Currency Symbols and change the value of "AZM" to "Points Currency".